# Extreme Value Analysis of Hurricane wind speeds

Tags: extreme-value, censoring, meteorology

As per the theory, an EVA with annual maxima presupposes that the series is complete, i.e. all years have an event. However, hurricanes don't occur every year, and so the hurricane wind speeds in Miami-Dade exhibit values in some years only, sometimes twice or more in a series from 1900 - 2020. How should I model this incompleteness in the series? Some potential answers include:

1. add zeros in years with no hurricanes
2. Use the average annual number of events (Gilleland and Katz 2016, p.20). Not sure if this is widespread though.
3. Use Generalized Pareto instead

What's a preferred way to handle this? are there better ways?
thanks!

Comment: How do you define "hurricane"?  If it is equivalent to a storm with a windspeed (or some property) exceeding a threshold, then you have (right)-censored data and you could consider using techniques for working with censored data.

Comment: by the saffir-simpson scale basically, on the basis of max winds speed and/or min pressure. It's as you say a storm with threshold. what specific techniques you have in mind?

Comment: There are many.  Survival analysis is the first place to look.

Comment: You could go for a Poisson-GP POT (Peaks Over Threshold) model, which seems to be answer 3. Years with no events will not be a problem. Another option is to use a longer block in the block maxima framework (e.g. two years) but this leads to a waste of data.

Comment: I recommend these texts for a principled approach to missing data in time series: Bretthorst's [*Bayesian Spectrum Analysis and Parameter Estimation*](https://bayes.wustl.edu/glb/book.pdf) and Jaynes's [*Probability Theory*](https://archive.org/details/XQUHIUXHIQUHIQXUIHX2), especially § 17.10.

Comment: @Yves thanks for the input! agreed. I'm remain curious though by the other two though. pglpm thanks! These references are useful but seem more geared towards signal analysis